# Embed PHP in an email to start a session and store variable

Tags: php, html, email, url, session

I'm trying to create a session variable when a user opens the email i send them. Everything is done with two .php files. (mailer.php and register.php)

mailer.php gets all the information for a user and sends them a email with a url to the register.php page.

I want to get a session variable (User_id) from mailer.php into register.php. I've put the following in the email that i send from mailer.php. I doubt it works, but it illustrates what I need.

```
`$message = $Url . "php session_start(); '$_SESSION[id]' = " . $row['user_id'] . " ?>";
...
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->Send();`
```

And then on the register page

```
`$userID = $_SESSION['id'];`
```

Comment: you cant. that's just bazaar. what are you actully trying to achieve?? - because this is NOT the way to do it

Comment: I don't want anyone to be able to go to www.mysite.com/register.php?userID=1234  and be able to change the users info. I need to know the UserID in register.php though. And they have to get there from a URL i send them in an email.

Comment: instead of $_SESSION['id'], you should be using $_GET['id']. Change to `$message=$Url."?id=".$_SESSION['id']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot attach function inside of the variable...Instead just create new table to store verification code,

```
function genRandomString() {
    $length = 10;
    $characters = ’0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz’;
    $string = ”;    
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $string;
}
$code = genRandomString();
$message = "http://localhost/start_session.php?verify=$code";
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
if($mail->Send()){
    echo 'Message Sent';
    // Then execute a query to insert the generated code to your database
}
```

When user opens his email and click the link, hell go to the verification page.

```
Match the verification code in the database using get variable and if found, start the session otherwise no session 
$code = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['verify'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM verifications WHERE verification_code=$code");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($rows > 0){
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
}
```

Comment: This is a much better way (and the normal way) of doing it.  Since the code is random, it is unlikely to be guessed.  You could also add a SHA1() function, to encrypt it as well.

Comment: Great info! 
Will the user know that the info is encrypted with the SHA1() function. Can any browser detect it?

Answer (score 0):

First off, php executes code once, and that is when the page loads.

With that said, correct me if I take your question wrong. You send a mail with an ID that ID you want to be able to fetch once someone opens the mail? I would recommend a regexp or a simple string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] ) to fetch it from the mail.

If you get the mail as raw text (which you will under normal circumstances) then just grab it.

Example mail:
"Hello12ID:5 My name is..."

A while ago I did handle strings like this, but here it goes.

> $id = substr($email, strpos($email,'ID:'), strpos($email, ' ', strpos($email,'ID')));
>   if (is_numeric ($id)) echo 'failed: '.$id.' is not numeric'; exit;

What it does is that it returns what is between 'ID' and the space therafter. In my case it is 5. So $id = 5 in this case. Then you just save that 5 into a session, which is possible to do at once as well, but better check so it grabs something okay before.

Hope it was what you meant.